# How to Detect Duplicate record in CRM 2013 on Create (Pre-Validate ) Plugin

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am writing a plugin which will detect duplicate ID on Create and will restrict the user to enter a new ID instead. NOTE : I CANT USE DEFAULT DUPLICATION METHODS PROVIDED BY MICROSOFT DYNAMICS 2013 or 2015.
THIS IS A SPECIAL CASE.
Following is the code of my plugin :

```
enter code here

if (entity.LogicalName == "new_studentinformation")
                {
                    // An accountnumber attribute should not already exist because
                    // it is system generated.
                    if (entity.Attributes.Contains("new_studentid") == false)
                    {
                        // Create a new accountnumber attribute, set its value, and add
                        // the attribute to the entity's attribute collection.
                        Random rndgen = new Random();
                        entity.Attributes.Add("new_studentid", rndgen.Next().ToString());
                    }
```

Now the  problem i am facing is in this line

if (entity.Attributes.Contains("new_studentid") == "Something")

how i can get the value entered by user in crm and compare it to my existing records ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to retrieve the entity from the plugin context as described in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309673.aspx):

```
IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)
serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
// The InputParameters collection contains all the data passed in the message request.
if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&
    context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
{
    // Obtain the target entity from the input parameters.
    Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
    // Your code here...
    var desiredValue = entity.GetAttributeValue<desiredtype>("desiredfield");
}
```

Comment: This is just the first part. The other one is a RetrieveMultiple asking for the condition, and if it gets records, then it is duplicate.

Comment: var desiredValue = entity.GetAttributeValue<desiredtype>("desiredfield");

This particular line will help me to get the value entered by user ?
and what about retrievemulitple?

Comment: Yes, if you register your plugin as post operation it'll most certainly contain the value entered by user. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327941.aspx